# Trouble with Element.getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm having some trouble using the `Element.getElementsByTagName` method.

With the following HTML:

```
<p id="test">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</p>​
```

And the following Javascript:

```
var a = document.getElementById('test');
var b = a.getElementsByTagName('p');
console.log(a);
console.log(b);​
```

`a` is set to the wrapping paragraph, but `b` is set to an empty NodeList (example: http://jsfiddle.net/xGjMN/).

I excpected `b` contain the two inner paragraph elements. Am I completely misunderstanding something here?

Comment: [validate, validate, validate](http://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot nest `<p>` tags.

Your nested `<p id="test"><p></p><p></p></p>` is rendered as:

```
<p id="test"></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p> <!-- From </p> -->
```

Hence `a.getElementsByTagName('p')` is an empty collection.

Comment: Ah, doh, of course you are right. I just threw this together for testing and did not consider the validity of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML will become the following dom:

```
<p id="test"> </p>
<p/>
<p/>
<p/>
```

because you can't nest paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

P block has a certain property it don't take the block element inside its scope , if you place any block element(ul,li,div,p etc) it will push out from its block.

```
<p id="test"></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

It renderends like this .

If you want to count the p block try to place inside the div block like this

```
<div id="test">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not prefix every line in your answer with four spaces. That formatting should only be used for code and monospace formatting. Your paragraphs won't be word-wrapped, making your answer harder to read.