# jquery show and hide divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with a yes|no question displayed by radio selectors. I have two divs each one containing different drop downs based on the yes|no response. I cannot figure out how to show one and hide the other.

[jsFiddle of this code](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamstarter/aB4jX/)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    $("input[name=radio_button]").change(function() {
        var test1= $(this).val();                   
        $("#"+test1).show();
        $("div.test2").hide();  
    }); 
    $("input[name=radio_button]").select(function() {
        var test2= $(this).val();       
        $("#"+test2).show();
        $("div.test1").hide();
    }); 
}); 

<p>
        <label class="required">&nbsp;</label>
        Yes <input name="radio_button" id="radio_button" type="radio" value="test2" onChange="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        No <input name="radio_button" id="radio_button" type="radio" value="test1" />
    </p>     
<p>
    <label class="required">Device: </label><br />
    <div id="test1" class="test1_div">
    <label style="font-weight:600;">test1</label>
        <select name="order.item" id="item" >
          <option value="default">Please Select item</option> 
        </select>
</div>
<div id="test2" class="test2_div">
<label style="font-weight:600;">item2</label>
        <select name="order.item" id="device">
          <option value="default">Please Select Device</option>             
        </select>
</div> 
</p>
```

Comment: There was a recent topic on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213357/show-hide-on-click/9213532#9213532 .  though you arent doing the same exact thing you can apply the same concept.

Comment: write an example in jsfiddle.net please

Comment: Post here or make a http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: I added a fiddle link to the question, http://jsfiddle.net/dreamstarter/aB4jX/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make one hidden and other visible , you have to first hide both the blocks then add `show()` on the block you want to see. This will work for you.

Comment: Kural, have you read [my previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330210/trouble-with-element-getelementsbytagname/9330501#comment11773980_9330501)? Please do not use code formatting by default.

Comment: both div blocks are hidden by default via CSS

Comment: you have add this dynamically, say when you show a block it set the style element to it saying display:block and inline script is the one which get more importance.. For it you have to set hide for both the block $("div.test2").hide();   $("div.test1").hide();  then show the one you want $("div.test1").show();

Comment: Thanks @KunalVashist that fixed my issue. here is the solved issue http://jsfiddle.net/dreamstarter/aB4jX/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your markup (html) is correct, try the following. It binds to click-events of those radio buttons (both of them), always hides both divs first, and then shows the appropiate div only (the one that belongs to the radio button clicked).

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("input[name=radio_button]").click(function() {
        var test= $(this).val();    

        $("div.test1, div.test2").hide(); //Hide both divs
        $("#"+test).show();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: tried this code and get the same results, the div's will show but if the yes radio is selected then the no afterwards (user may have changed its mind) both div's remain shown.